# pd finite for finite module over local CM ring?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let (R,m) be a CM ring of dimension d, and M a finite R- module. Is pd M always finite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Put $k=R/m$. Then $k$ is of finite projective dimension if and only if $R$ is regular. This is the famous theorem of Auslander-Buchsbaum, Serre (see for instance Bruns-Herzog Cohen-Macaulay rings theorem 2.2.7 for a proof). So the residual field of a non-regular CM ring will give a counter-example.